# Openssl 1.0.2p decryption failing?

Tags: encryption, openssl, pycrypto

I am using 1.0.2p to encrypt the file using the following command.

```
#openssl aes-128-cbc  -e -k 'abcdefghijklmnop' -in my.txt -out myencrypt.txt
```

My decryption is based out of Crypto.Cipher python module.
 Here is my code. However, I am unable to decrypt the text successfully.
 I am unsure on what am I missing here?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as encrypt_file:
        ciphertext = encrypt_file.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
    with open("plain.txt", "wb") as plain_file:
        plain_file.write(dec)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    decrypt_file('myencrypt.txt', 'abcdefghijklmnop')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be that OpenSSL 1.0.2 still uses MD5 as its hashing algorithm instead of SHA. I am not super familiar with this Python library, but from [the docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html#Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP.new) it looks like the default hashing algorithm is SHA1.

From the parameters section of new():

> **hashAlgo** *(hash object)* – The hash function to use. This can be a module under Crypto.Hash or an existing hash object created from any of such modules. If not specified, Crypto.Hash.SHA1 is used.

So what I believe is happening is that your encryption line (using OpenSSL 1.0.2) uses MD5 when encrypting, but the Python library is defaulting to SHA1. So you would either need to update your OpenSSL version and/or specify the hashing algorithm in your Python code when calling `new()`.

I believe OpenSSL was updated in 1.1.0 to use a SHA algorithm for hashing. I have actually ran into this problem when trying to decrypt an archive from an older server, using OpenSSL for both encryption and decryption but the versions won't match. If you have any issues decrypting an archive from an older version of OpenSSL, you may have to specify the older hashing algorithm with `-md md5`, like:

```
openssl enc -aes256 -d -in your/input/file.encrypt -out your/output/file -md md5
```